# nerdctl port not exposed

Tags: port, containerd, nerdctl

I started to used containerd instead of docker. I did what was to be installed for containerd with nerdctl. Nginx was the container I ran. Though container port 80 is mapped, it's not exposed. I've checked whether firewall blocks but none.

`nerdctl run -d -p 80:80 70999c4a17c7`

```
CONTAINER ID    IMAGE                             COMMAND                   CREATED           STATUS    PORTS                 NAMES
0416dd502f86    docker.io/library/nginx:latest    "/docker-entrypoint.…"    55 minutes ago    Up        0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp    nginx
```

So what could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found your question having just had the same issue! I did exactly the same as you, and indeed found the same: it does not work when you expose port 80.

I then tried a *different* port:

`nerdctl run -d -p 8081:80 nginx`

... and that *did* work. With no additional settings needed.

So I had a look at what else might be listening on port 80 ...

`sudo lsof  -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -Pnl | grep :80`

... and (in my case) `limactl` was listening on port 80. I assume that would explain why nginx could not *also* use port 80. So it seems like you just need to use a different port (probably simpler than digging into lima settings).